# What are these ifconfig interfaces on macOS

Tags: network-interface, macos, ifconfig

I have a MacBook Pro 15" 2018 (Touch Bar). I see it has a lot of network interfaces. I would like to know what they are/what they do. I did some research but I couldn't really figure out all of them, here are their `SCNetworkInterfaceInfo.UserDefinedName` with information I was able to find from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/267660/can-someone-please-explain-ifconfig-output-in-mac-os-x/267669#267669):

- ap1: ?
- awdl0: ?
- llw0: ?
- utun0: ?
- utun1: ?
- lo0: loopback (localhost)
- gif0: Software Network Interface
- stf0: 6to4 tunnel interface
- en0: physical wireless
- en1: Thunderbolt 1
- en2: Thunderbolt 2
- en3: Thunderbolt 3
- en4: Thunderbolt 4
- en5: iBridge / Apple T2 Controller
- en6: Bluetooth PAN
- en8: iPhone USB
- en9: VM network interface
- en10: iPad
- bridge0: Thunderbolt Bridge

The search engine for the Unix & Linux StackExchange is offline as of the time I'm posting this question.
Thanks in advance.

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: active
ap1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: inactive
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: active
en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: inactive
en4: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 10 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 7 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 8 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: active
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
en10: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: active
en8: flags=8822<BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    status: inactive
```

Comment: - gif0: Software interface, It can tunnel IPV4 and IPV6 - Stf0: Is very similar to gif0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the ones that you don't have:

- `ap1`: Access Point. This is used if you are using your MacBook as a wireless host where you are sharing its connection.
- `awdl0`: Apple Wireless Direct Link. WIFI p2p connection for things like AirDrop, Airplay, etc. Also used for Bluetooth.
- `llw0`: Low-latency WLAN Interface. Used by the Skywalk system.
- `utun0`: Tunneling interface. Used for VPN connections to tunnel traffic or for software like Back To My Mack.
- `utun1`: Same as utun01

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on these, too? Although I have their names and I'm guessing what they do, I would like to know for sure: `gif0`, `stf0`, `en9: VM network interface`, `bridge0: Thunderbolt Bridge`. Thank you very much